# How do I include months that have no data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to create a report that shows how many training records will expire within a chosen date range however when I run the report it excludes months that have no training records going out of date. I have tried various solutions I've seen posted but I haven't been able to get any of them to work in my case.

This is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(ISNULL(TRAININGRECORDID, 0)) AS NUMBEROFRECORDS
,DEPARTMENTNUMBER
,DATENAME( Month, EXPIRY ) + '-' + DATENAME( Year, EXPIRY ) AS [MONTHYEAR]
FROM Training_Records TR
JOIN Departments TD ON TR.DEPARTMENTID = TD.DEPARTMENTID
WHERE TR.EXPIRY IS NOT NULL
AND TD.DEPARTMENTNUMBER IN (@DEPTNO)
AND TR.EXPIRY BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY TD.DEPARTMENTNUMBER, DATENAME(Year, TR.EXPIRY), DATENAME(Month, TR.EXPIRY)
ORDER BY TD.DEPARTMENTNUMBER, [MONTHYEAR]
```

An example of results from this query looks like this:

```
NUMBEROFRECORDS DEPARTMENTNUMBER MONTHYEAR
1                21              April-2023
4                23              June-2023
1                83              August-2023
```

I am displaying the results of this query in a matrix with MONTHYEAR as the columns. In the example above the report will display April, June and August 2023 but will skip over the months May, July 2023 because there are no records going out of date in those months but despite that I still want them displayed in my report/returned in my query.

I've tried various solutions I've found on here but none of them have worked for me. How would I go about including these months with no records going out of date?

Comment: SQL can't show you data that doesn't exist, so you will need to create it first. In this case, that means creating all of the combinations of months and years you want to see in the output. A common solution in a situation like this (where the values you need to generate can be done by simple deterministic arithmetic) is to use a table of integers, also known as a "tally table". [Here](https://riptutorial.com/sql-server/example/11099/generating-a-date-range-with-a-tally-table) is an example. You can then `left join` your actual data to the "calendar" you generate from the tally table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first get all of the months, and then *outer* join to them ([not using `BETWEEN`](https://sqlblog.org/dates#between)). Here is an example that gets April, May, June, and July, and then shows how you would outer join that against your table.

```
DECLARE @StartDate date = '20220405', 
        @EndDate   date = '20220708';

;WITH Months(TheMonth) AS 
(
  SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@StartDate), MONTH(@StartDate), 1)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, TheMonth) 
    FROM Months
    WHERE TheMonth < DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@EndDate), MONTH(@EndDate), 1)
)
SELECT TheMonth -- , COALESCE(SUM({your table}.{column}),0)
FROM Months AS m
-- LEFT OUTER JOIN  {your table}
-- ON {your table}.{date column} >= m.TheMonth
-- AND {your table}.{date column} < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, m.TheMonth);
```

Output:

| TheMonth |
| --- |
| 2022-04-01 |
| 2022-05-01 |
| 2022-06-01 |
| 2022-07-01 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1a9b221945c341bace51bd0382265ef5)

If your range could last more than 100 months, you'll need to add:

```
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Comment: Surprised you've gone for an rCTE here, rather than a Tally. The latter is more performant, and avoids the necessity for setting `MAXRECURSION` in the `OPTION` clause for "larger" volumes of rows, as there is no recursion.

Comment: @Larnu for sets of months I don't think it's very likely you're ever going to see performance issues or the need for maxrecursion. 100 months is a LOT and I suspect aggregating data across 100 months will cause more performance problems than a recursive CTE ever could.  When everyone is on SQL Server 2022 I will certainly use GENERATE_SERIES for this but in the meantime explaining that they need to create another table or function or use system objects is often met with resistance. Not worth it. YMMV.

Comment: I must admit, I haven't seen great performance from `GENERATE_SERIES` when testing. Don't know if that's because it has a sort operation in it, which is hindering it, but it's had more similar performance to an rCTE in my sandbox environment. I've taken it with a grain of salt for now, as it is still in preview. (I won't lie, I've been hoping someone with your level of knowledge has done some testing and can prove my experience wrong!  )

Comment: @Larnu A more generic comment: try to hold off until at least the next CTP.

Comment: Yeah, what i was planning. I always take performance test with a pinch on salt on early CTPs, and the fact that it was so much slower than I expected strongly suggested it was (for lack of better words) "a work in progress". I do hope to see those improvements over the coming releases.